# Dismiss NSSavePanel under sandbox environment

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, nssavepanel

In a sandbox environment, the `NSSavePanel` is controlled by the Powerbox process.

I'm wondering if there's a way to dismiss the `NSSavePanel` without having the user to explicitly click the 'cancel' or presses Esc? For example, if I want to add the 'dismiss' button in the Accessory view of the `NSSavePanel`, is there a way to do that?

Comment: What would be the use case..?  It sounds like a very confusing user experience to me the way it's described.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Apple prohibits invoking ok: method under sandbox, but the cancel: still works. Verified with a testing app.